# How to call different fields from different content in same view?

Tags: views

I have content type Say "A" and for that i want to create view, in this view i want to add a field which is from different content type say "B", reason is here in the B content type i have fee category and assigning the rent value for each category, and this node of content type is referring in a content type A with entity reference, something like this in screen shot. as of now i created view for content type A,and added the field of content type B, but the values add in the content B are not displaying in the view of content A

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the values of "*cage rent per day*" from B to A's view, you must add a relation in content A view with the "*Fee category*" field.

Then normally you should select in the "*cage rent per day*" field settings in view A, the relation you've just added.

However, the idea is to have some reference to content B in view A to access B's fields values. And this is possible with relations .

Comment: in relation what we need to choose?author??

Comment: Normally you need to choose a reference field to type B in type A. This way you'll get all the values of B in A. And then when you add/edit a field in A, you can select the relation to type B.

Comment: I got it by following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YPQZLt3LHTY&hd=1 ...........and your answer also related to this video ): thanks for helping

Comment: Happy you've got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Relationship is what you're looking for.
I found this on Google - [Drupal Views relationships and entity reference](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-sense-drupal-views-relationships-and-entity-references)

Comment: its for entity reference field, and they are saying content A,B,C iam confused now, i want to get the values of filed from content B in content A , with their corresponding entity reference field. just like in screen shot.but

Comment: As far as I understand content A has an entity ref. field that refer to a node of type B and you want to show the value of a field in the referenced node (of type B) in a view that shows all nodes of type A.  If that's correct, then you should add a relationship to the content refered by the entity ref. and then you should be able to select the rent field from the ref. node (of type B..)

Comment: My requirement is like this: please take look in content A , there is field called cage rent per day, its a field from content B, and in the left column You could see the Fee category which is entity reference from content B, here in content A whatever i am updating the fee category in content B i can able to fetch here in content A view, but problem is i am not able get the values of cage rent per day which i am updating in content B while updating with the fee category, Note: only the fee category is entity reference field, not cage rent per day [its a text field from content B ].